# Why does my adapted f/2.8 lens make very dark images in manual and action mode?

Tags: lens, exposure, manual-mode

I'm using a Sony A7 II with adapter with a Canon EF 24-70mm f/2.8L and a Canon 16-35mm f/2.8L both with the same settings, but the exposure on the 24-70mm is darker in the manual and action modes, but in automatic and portrait it shoots completely fine only with a bit of lag.

I tried detaching the connection between the lens and the body and just slightly connecting them to generate a image; I think there's something wrong with the lens. Like it has gone really dark for some reason.

I have a feeling that something in the lens needs to be fixed.

Any advice or help to fix it would greatly be appreciated.

---

I don't think the body/adapter is the issue, as I have also tried it on my Canon 60D, and the same issue occurs.

Answer (score -3):

Your maximum f/stop is different at different focal lengths, even with the same lens. I had a 55-255mm lens that at 55mm max f/4 but at 255mm my f/stop would not go below f/5.

Comment: except the OP's lenses have a constant maximum aperture of f/2.8 each. Those lenses have f/2.8 _throughout the zoom range_. I'm not familiar with any 55-255mm lenses, but if you're talking about the [Canon 55-250mm f/4-f/5.6](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/lenses/ef/telephoto-zoom/ef-s-55-250mm-f-4-5-6-is-ii), then indeed, it had a variable max aperture.